# Why is my legend in QGIS using cached data?

Tags: qgis, legend

I have a legend... multiple legends as a matter of fact. Even though I clear them out and start from scratch, I am getting old cached data of what my color ranges used to be, instead of what they've been changed to. I can't get my new colors in the legend... and even the labels are wrong from what I originally had them as.

[image: Current]
[image: Cached]

Comment: Is it because I haven't yet changed my chloropleth colors to the new ones? Do I really have to do it in order?

Comment: For the _Item properties_ of your label in composer, did you try updating the legend from there?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this turned out to be that I still had the previous colors utilized in some maps of my composer. I had to unlock and refresh those layers.